# Data binding with multiple domain classes in XML request

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I noticed in the User Documentation that it's possible to split URL parameters intended for different domain classes as such:

```
/book/save?book.title=The%20Stand&author.name=Stephen%20King
```

And then you could pass the values for their intended domain classes as such:

```
def b = new Book(params.book)
def a = new Auther(params.author)
```

I'm planning to build a web services API with Grails and was wondering how this would work if I would be utilizing XML request in the request body rather than passing the parameters via URL parameters. What would the XML body look like in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
def s = '<xml><book title="The Stand" /><author name="Stephen King"/></xml>'
def x = new XmlSlurper().parseText(s)

x.book.each{b-> new Book(b.attributes()).save()}
x.author.each{a-> new Author(a.attributes()).save()}
```

In the Controller Grails enhances HttpServletRequest, so you can use

```
request.XML
```

which is instance of XmlSlurper's GPathResult class that allows parsing of an incoming XML request.

ref: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html